# Discovering group laws on algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

The addition law for the group structure of an elliptic curve is geometrically very elegant, but it's hard to see how you would guess it if you didn't already know about it by other means. Of course, historically it came from the addition laws for elliptic integrals where it was natural to look for them.

So one wonders: given an algebraic variety $X$ over a field $k$ how would you discover if it has an algebraic group structure and then find out what the group structure(s) is/are. Is there a criterion and a procedure?

Comment: This seems quite similar to asking:  how do you decide if a set has the structure of a group?  (I don't know the answer for infinite sets, though that's probably just my ignorance.)  In this case it's obvious that any variety that is the underlying set of an algebraic group has a transitive automorphism group, and such a variety can be given the structure of a quotient of that group—so probably the additional obstruction is whether there's a transitive (sub)group of automorphisms and a point whose stabiliser in that subgroup is normal.  But that's probably ineffective to test.

Comment: Actually, I think a better, though probably still ineffective, test is whether there's a complement $G$ in the full automorphism group $A$ to the stabiliser $A_x$ of a (rational) point, in the sense that $G \times A_x \to A$ is a bijection of sets.  (So I guess one should also require the existence of a rational point!)

Comment: Another necessary condition that excludes a lot of cases of @LSpice's comment is that the (co)tangent bundle should be trivial. This already tells you that for smooth projective curves the only possible ones with a group structure are curves of genus $1$.

Comment: "historically it came from the addition laws for elliptic integrals" --
I thought the chords-and-tangents construction for the Diophantine equation
came first, though it took a long time until
that became a group law.  See Norbert Schappacher's
"Développement de la loi de groupe sur une cubique" 
(Max-Planck-Inst. für Mathematik, 1990).

Comment: @Noam D. Elkies since, as you say, the original chord and tangent process is not a group law (not associative), it is reasonable for the discovery of addition formulas for elliptic integrals to be considered the “starting point” for recognizing the presence of a group law on elliptic curves.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, is there an easy example of a variety with transitive automorphism group but non-trivial cotangent bundle?

Comment: @LSpice: An easy example is the projective line, or more generally 
projective space of any dimension, or even a Grassmannian.
Also a smooth quadric hypersurface (past the cases where it's already covered by the Grassmannian example).